# How can I include multiple pygame programs in a single .py file so they can be accessed from the same window

Tags: python, pygame

What I want to do is, I want to present different smaller games as options on the initial window to choose from. So whatever the game option user selects, that game will run in the same window. Is that possible and if it is then how?

Comment: It is possible, you can make a simple menu in the first window. But it is generally not considered a good practice, even for one game to just have one file. Look at examples of python programs on sourceforge to see how people structure their code, separating model, view, controller, documentation, configuration etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you want in pseudocode:

```
class Menu():
    #Has all menu-related knick-knacks

def main(screen):
    if on_main_menu == True:
        Menu.draw(screen)
    if Menu.start_button_1.is_pressed:
        on_main_menu = False
        playing_game1 = True
    if Menu.start_button_2.is_pressed:
        on_main_menu = False
        playing_game2 = True

while playing_game1:
    #play the epic game
while playing_game2:
    #play the even more epic game
```

Comment: Thank you this shall do for some basic  games